# A measure which flags a change based on time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like below with three columns: `Year`, `Type1`, and `Type2`. I need a measure that can flag a change in `Type2` for each `Type1` over year. A measure that gives a column like `Change in Type2` below:

[image]

For example, this measure could give `1` if `Type2` in `Type1` has changed next year, and it gives `0` if `Type2` stays the same so that at the end I can have this table:

[image]

Is there any measure that can calculate this?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the change in `Type2` by comparing versus the previous year:

```
Change in Type2 =
VAR CurrType2 = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Type2] )
VAR CurrYear = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Year] )
VAR PrevType2 =
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Type2] ),
        ALL ( Table1[Type2] ),
        Table1[Year] = CurrYear - 1
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( PrevType2 ), BLANK(), IF ( CurrType2 = PrevType2, 0, 1 ) )
```

The sum of the change is then pretty simple:

```
Change Sum = SUMX ( VALUES ( Table1[Type1] ), [Change in Type2] )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time. It worked nicely!